# T-SQL Finding Percentage/Ratio of Two Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, pivot-table

So I have the following code

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ( ORG_CODE_PROV = 'ABC' ) THEN 'DEF' 
         ELSE ORG_CODE_PROV 
       END      AS ORG_CODE_PROV , 
       THE_DATE, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( THE_NUMBER > '1' ) THEN 'Valid' 
         ELSE 'Invalid' 
       END      AS THE_NUMBER, 
       Count(*) AS Amount 
FROM   THE_TABLE
GROUP  BY ORG_CODE_PROV , 
          CASE 
            WHEN ( ORG_CODE_PROV = 'ABC' ) THEN 'DEF' 
            ELSE ORG_CODE_PROV 
          END, 
          THE_DATE, 
          CASE 
            WHEN ( THE_NUMBER > '1' ) THEN 'Valid' 
            ELSE 'Invalid' 
          END
```

It produces something along the lines of (allbeit with a load more data)

```
ORG_CODE_PROV | THE_DATE | THE_NUMBER | Amount
----------------------------------------------
ABC           | 201204   | Invalid    | 50
ABC           | 201204   | Valid      | 200
ABC           | 201205   | Valid      | 200
ABC           | 201206   | Invalid    | 50
ABC           | 201206   | Valid      | 100
ZYZ           | 201204   | Invalid    | 20
XYZ           | 201204   | Valid      | 200
```

What I would like however is to show the percentage of invalid 'numbers' against the total e.g.

```
ORG_CODE_PROV | THE_DATE | THE_PERCENTAGE
----------------------------------------------
ABC           | 201204   | 20    
ABC           | 201205   | 0
ABC           | 201206   | 33
ZYZ           | 201204   | 9
```

I'm guessing I might have to use a pivot table but got seriously stuck. Any help?

Thanks,

JJ

**[EDIT]**
The `ORG_CODE_PROV` values are known as they are included in an IN clause further down the line. Not sure if that helps at all?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the values. In the 2nd table it's (50/(50+200)) for 20%, (0/(0+200)) for 0%, (50/(50+100)) for 33% and (20/(20+200)) for 9%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    ORG_CODE_PROV,
    THE_DATE,
    100.0 * SUM(case the_number when 'invalid' then amount else 0 end) /
    nullif(SUM(amount),0)    
from 
(
     Select * from yourquery
) results
group by
    ORG_CODE_PROV,
    THE_DATE
```

Comment: note that for `yourquery` here you should use the whole text of the query in the question

Comment: Cheers - it's obvious once it's down in front of me!

Answer (score 0):

You can have calculation within a Count(), as follows:

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN ( ORG_CODE_PROV = 'ABC' ) THEN 'DEF' 
     ELSE ORG_CODE_PROV 
   END AS ORG_CODE_PROV, 
   THE_DATE, 
   COUNT( CASE WHEN ( THE_NUMBER > '1' ) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) / COUNT( * ) AS THE_PERCENT -- % Invalid
--, COUNT( CASE WHEN ( THE_NUMBER > '1' ) THEN 1 END ) / COUNT( * ) AS THE_OTHER_PERCENT -- % Valid
FROM THE_TABLE
GROUP BY CASE 
     WHEN ( ORG_CODE_PROV = 'ABC' ) THEN 'DEF' 
     ELSE ORG_CODE_PROV 
   END, THE_DATE
```